# Libcloud library in python equivalent to nodejs

Tags: python, node.js, provider, libcloud, apiclient

we can use libcloud in python as api interface services since its a cloud library .so like this how can we use this library in nodejs language? Any idea guys,as far I know there is one library SDK but its an was official one.any other guys?   Thanks,Indu

Answer (score 2):

The [pkgcloud](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkgcloud) module is similar to libcloud.

It's not quite as fully-featured but supports many of the popular compute and storage providers.

Comment: Thanks Fuiler, which means we cannot  able to access libcloud in nodejs ,am i right?

Comment: Thanks Fuiler, which means we cannot  able to access libcloud in nodejs ,am i right?

Comment: Through pkgcloud,we can create provider connector using nodejs?

Comment: libcloud is written in Python, which won't run natively in the V8 JavaScript engine used by Node.js. pkgcloud will allow you to connect to multiple providers, for example via its [EC2 connector](https://github.com/pkgcloud/pkgcloud/blob/master/docs/providers/amazon.md).

Comment: Thanks Fuiler,multiple providers supporting but when i give interroute provider it doesnot support ,whether any options to support this provider?

Comment: The above mentioned provider interroute is not in supported provider;s list.In that provider i need to get image is it possible?

Comment: If you have a specific requirement to use Interoute, please update your question to include this rather valuable information.

Comment: Hi, here is my code in python , i need to list images in cloustack:from libcloud.compute.types import Provider
from libcloud.compute.providers import get_driver
from libcloud.common.base import Response

#import libcloud.security as sec
#sec.VERIFY_SSL_CERT = False
#USER = 'ACCESSKEY'
#API_KEY = 'SECRETKEY'

Driver = get_driver(Provider.CLOUDSTACK)
url = 'MY URL'

conn = Driver(key=USER, secret=API_KEY, url=url)
print "Connection established"
images = conn.list_images()
print images
#print len(images)
#print images[:5]

Comment: In that showing error like this :   body = self.parse_body()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/common/base.py", line 195, in parse_body
    driver=self.connection.driver)
libcloud.common.types.MalformedResponseError: <MalformedResponseException in <libcloud.compute.drivers.cloudstack.CloudStackNodeDriver object at 0x7fc356f55b50> 'Failed to parse JSON'>: 'Unknown_ApiKey'
   Where iam missing?

Comment: Hi, why can't i use the following methods in my code? also showing error like above.